# Why is there a comma before "my friends" in this sentence?

Tags: punctuation, greetings, forms-of-address

In the sentence below, why is "*my friends*" set off with a comma?

> “It is a great misfortune to be alone, **my friends**; and it must be believed that solitude can quickly destroy reason.” 
>   
> ― Jules Verne, The Mysterious Island

How do you explain this grammatically?

Comment: It's called "direct address" and it requires a comma.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's called the **vocative comma**. When you address your listener or reader by name or by a description, written English grammar requires that you set off the noun or noun phrase by which you name your audience with commas. It appears in your example sentence because the speaker is directly addressing his friends.

For example, this sentence does not directly address Fred:

> I saw Fred steal my roses.

The next sentence addresses Fred. It's how you'd say the same thing if you were talking *to* Fred:

> **Fred,** I saw you steal my roses.

Here are some common sentences that require the vocative comma when written:

> Nice job**, Fred**!
>
> **Ladies and gentlemen,** … (at the beginning of a speech)
>
> **Dear Fred,** … (at the beginning of a letter)
>
> **Gentlemen,** start your engines. (Just before the beginning of an auto race.)
>
> I can only say in my defense**, your honor,** that the roses were grown from seeds that the plaintiff had stolen from me. (Addressing the judge during a trial.)

### Some background

It's called "vocative" by analogy with the "vocative case". In some languages, you use an altered form of a person's name when addressing them directly. For example, in Latin, when you address *Quintus* directly, you call him *Quinte;* when you address *Julius,* you call him *Julī;* and in Catholicism, when you address *Dominus* ("the lord") in prayers and hymns, you call him *Domine.*

English doesn't have a vocative case, but it does use special intonation for direct address, which almost amounts to the same thing. At the start of a sentence, you normally say a vocative phrase in a higher pitch than what follows; in the middle or at the end of a sentence, you normally say a vocative phrase in a lower pitch than the surrounding or preceding words. The comma in writing suggests this change of intonation as well as the slight pause or extended final syllable that also usually occurs in a vocative phrase.

The word "vocative" itself comes from the Latin word for "call", because it's how you call to someone. The same root appears in "vocation" (a calling), "vocabulary" (what you call stuff), and "convocation" (a meeting where many people are called together).

Comment: +1 But since Vatican II there aren't many lay Catholics left in the US who use Latin.

Comment: @StoneyB Indeed there aren't, and even before Vatican II, I think most lay Catholics knew almost no Latin. However, a church-organist friend keeps asking me for help with the Latin in the hymns they're singing, Latin sacred music is still sung quite a bit in concert halls, and not long ago ELU had [this question](http://j.mp/1Hlyx0N) about the Latin vocative in English. It doesn't really matter, though; any other language with a vocative case would also make a good illustration (or a better illustration, since Latin only has a distinct vocative case in the 2nd declension).

Comment: @Ben Kovitz: `English grammar requires that you set off the noun or noun phrase by which you name your audience with commas...` To be precise, in spoken English the vocative phrase is separated from the rest of the clause with syntactic pauses; in writing, these pauses are conventionally represented by commas.

Comment: Note that in rapid speech, the pauses optionally disappear.  (In these cases, we might reasonably say the pauses were never there to begin with!)  We can consider the commas structural, as in many other cases where they were originally related to pauses but can no longer be reliably associated with them.

Comment: We use other terms similarly to *vocative*.  For example, we say *dative* in reference to PPs headed by *to*, though Present-Day English clearly has no morphological dative case.

Comment: @TRomano It says "written English grammar". I tried to explain the subtleties of the spoken vocative in the second-to-last paragraph. I'd be delighted to hear if you think it's right.

Comment: Ain't no such thang.

Comment: @snailboat Indeed, I don't think commas always signify pauses. They're strictly a written convention, but they often (not always) signify aspects of sentence structure that in speech are signified by intonation or changes of rhythm.

Comment: Just in case you're referring to my comment, to say that a comma there is the conventional typographic representation of a certain kind of syntactic pause in spoken English is not to say that "commas *always* signify pauses".

Comment: @BenKovitz If you're interested, there's a great history of western punctuation by Parkes called *Pause and Effect* which goes into great detail about the gradual transition from commas indicating pauses exclusively to being in many cases a purely structural marker.

Comment: @snailboat: the pauses do not "disappear", they become attenuated in proportion to the speed of delivery, with the attenuation often being compensated for by a change in tonal contour. Writing is virtual language, not language.

Comment: @snailboat Thanks! I'll check it out. I figured that that's probably how present-day comma conventions came about, but the historical details are always interesting. In general, I think it's a fallacy to expect or demand that writing exactly represent speech.

Comment: You're putting words into my mouth, Ben, so to speak. Sloppy way to argue a point.

Comment: The phrase "purely structural" is meaningless.  Structure of what?

Comment: @TRomano I'm not arguing with you or even disagreeing with you. My comments to you start with "@TRomano". About "purely structural", you can push snailboat for detail, but I think explaining that idea clearly if you don't get it from context is probably too complex for comments. It sounds like we all agree that commas don't necessarily signify pauses, but in this case they correspond to _something_ intonational/rhythmic in speech that distinguishes a vocative phrase.

Comment: @BenKovitz: OK. It seemed you were, and in the process my position was getting distorted. I am speaking of the relationship between syntax and punctuation, i.e. of *syntactic* pauses--as distinct from *rhetorical* pauses. Writing systems can represent spoken contours to a greater or lesser degree. Some didn't even create word boundaries, for example; no spaces anywhere; whereas others tried to find analogues for the synactic pauses in natural speech, and attempted to encode "parsing rhythms" which led them to sometimes ignore word boundaries and connect syllables of adjacent words "naturally".

Comment: @TRomano I know you've already flatly rejected (in previous comment threads) my usual references about why we might want to consider the written language as something more than a simple representation of spoken language.  So please don't take this as arguing with you; I just want to give Ben Kovitz another reference.  Ben, in case *you're* interested, the introduction to Nunberg's 1990 monograph *The Linguistics of Punctuation* is one of my favorite essays on the subject, starting with "It should no longer be necessary to defend the view that writing is *truly* language, ..."

Comment: @snailboat. Of course, just as you have flatly rejected my contention that writing is *virtual* language, not language. Any definition of language that also fits writing is an incomplete definition of language.

Comment: @TRomano Well, yes, I do reject your assertion, but that's not important.  We stopped before we ever began to debate the point, and I don't mean to argue it with you now.  I just wanted to leave a link with a reference for further reading :-)

Comment: @snailboat Well, that settles it: Nunberg is going to top of my reading list, maybe even ahead of _[Through the Looking Glass](http://amzn.com/0312610491)_! I have indeed often found myself annoyed with linguists for discounting the reality and importance of written language merely because it's learned in school, artificial, and ruled by consciously articulated prescriptions. I'd definitely like to hear from one who thinks otherwise. Thanks!

Comment: @BenKovitz Of *course* written language is language. Written English includes many distinct English dialects, some pedantic and artificial but others of great historical importance and contemporary influence. I am constantly amused by the disproportionate amount of energy the colloquialist ideologues spend analyzing constructions which never appear in speech, or only in the speech of those who have learned them from reading.