# What's on the menu for dinner mom?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

How do you usually ask your mother/wife etc. "what they have cooked to eat for a meal like a lunch or a dinner?
Does it sound idiomatic and polite to ask:

> - What's on the menu mom?

If not then please tell me what shall I ask such a person?

Comment: [on vocative commas](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/56979/why-is-there-a-comma-before-my-friends-in-this-sentence/56982#56982)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Informally you might ask:

> What's for lunch/supper?

There are a dozen other more or less formal ways to pose the question, such as:

> What's on the (lunch/supper) menu?
>   What can we look forward to for lunch/supper?
>   What have you done/prepared for lunch/supper?
>   Anything interesting/new/different for lunch/supper?
>   What's coming up for lunch/supper?
>   Smells lovely. What is it?

and so on.

You can add **mom/mum** - **love/honey/darling** etc to any of the above.

Your own suggestion is fine.

Comment: Thank you @Ronald Sole; I have the answer to my question now, but just one more question here! Would it sound idiomatic and natural to say: **what have you cooked?** rather than **what have you done?** Whilst here they both mean the same to me.

Comment: That’s fine as long as it’s not a salad or similar.

Comment: Thank you very much @Ronald Sole. :)